# Ionic "ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED"

Tags: android, html, cordova, ionic-framework, arcgis

I am having issues deploying my Ionic app to Android specifically my Arcgis embedded map. I get the error "net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED"

After researching I found this can be caused because the address is an HTTP::// and not an HTTPS::// but even after following other peoples solutions for changing the AndroidManifest

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

I am still getting the same error. Because this is an embedded link I cannot change it to https::// I even attempted to remove the

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

But still receiving the same error. The map works perfectly when run from the browser but once deployed to android it breaks. Ill link files below

HTML File

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>

  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <div class="embed-container">
  <iframe width="500" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" title="ShipWrecks"
  src="//stubbsie.maps.arcgis.com/apps/Embed/index.html?webmap=054a9d0eb0984141be2863a8c3abb705&extent=-9.5902,51.2352,-5.5335,52.6355&home=true&zoom=true&previewImage=true&scale=true&search=true&searchextent=true&details=true&legend=true&active_panel=legend&basemap_gallery=true&disable_scroll=true&theme=dark"></iframe>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
android:targetSandboxVersion="1" 
android:versionCode="1" 
android:versionName="0.0.1" 
package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <supports-screens 
    android:anyDensity="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application 
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" 
    android:supportsRtl="true" 
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">


        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
</manifest>
```

Config.xml Here I attempted to add in the line android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to the application and did not work.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
            <string>We use your location for full functionality of certain app features.</string>
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="20" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20.png" width="20" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@2x.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@3x.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="48" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-24@2x.png" width="48" />
        <icon height="55" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-27.5@2x.png" width="55" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="88" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-44@2x.png" width="88" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="172" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-86@2x.png" width="172" />
        <icon height="196" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-98@2x.png" width="196" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1125" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2436h.png" width="2436" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2436" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2436h.png" width="1125" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
</widget>
```

I am unsure where to go from here how to get it working. As this is an instrumental part of my app I really need this to run.

Comment: Did you add `<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />` to `config.xml` inside `edit-config`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by changing my Config.xml and updating it with this code.

```
<access origin="*" />
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
    </edit-config>
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
```

And removing from both Config and my AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />` to `config.xml` inside `edit-config`.

```
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
          <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
          <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
    </edit-config>
    ...
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be caused when passing plain data to an insecure URL. Before adding `<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />` to config.xml, check if you can make the request as https, not http.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the clear text is not allowed.

But the solution is simple.

In the folder resorces/android/xml there is a file network_security_config.xml

Please add the local domain o insecurity domain or IP.

for instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.0.7</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.0.12</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.10.1.112</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Then, please, run again... Thats all.

Comment: An interesting page for those who don't know how to setup this :
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-3-error-resource-xml-network-security-config-not-found/175412

Answer (score 0):

Following the file path below you will arrive at three possible solutions to solve your problem

first add this in this path
resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
     <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <trust-anchors>
           <certificates src="system" />
       </trust-anchors>
   </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain>localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">YOUR DOMAIN/IP</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Add this`<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />`  on
config.xml in platform android .

```
<platform name="android">       
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
    </edit-config>     
  </platform>
```

Add this`<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />`  in this path.
platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```